# Ordering of python set from NumPy array

Tags: python, numpy, set

I am having trouble figuring out why I make a set from a NumPy array, Python swaps the order of elements:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([2])
B = np.array([2, 8])
setA = set(A)
setB = set(B)

In [6]: A
Out[6]: [2]

In [7]: B
Out[7]: [2, 8]

In [8]: setA
Out[8]: set([2])

In [9]: setB
Out[9]: set([8, 2])

In [10]: list(setA.union(setB))
Out[10]: [8, 2]

In [11]: np.union1d(A,B).tolist()
Out[11]: [2, 8]
```

Why isn't the order wouldn't be maintained when I created `set(B)`?

Comment: `print set([8,2]) == set([2,8])`

Comment: I agree that it in some sense it doesn't matter, but nonetheless I still think that *why* is a valid question...

Comment: why is complicated and has to do with the hashing methodology.

Answer (score 3):

`set`s by definition have no order - they are instead created so as to optimize certain operations such as those testing for containment. Therefore, you should never rely on order preservation when you create / add elements to a set.

Answer (score 2):

Sets are [unordered collections of unique elements](http://docs.python.org/library/sets.html), so set([2,8]) and set([8, 2]) are exactly the same. Why do you care? Maybe a set is not what you need...

Comment: Doh! That makes sense. Order does make a difference, so I might have to use another approach. Thanks.